# To validate Instagram username using https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1 in angular 4+ version

Tags: javascript, angular, instagram

I need to validate the instagram username with the `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1` URL. However, the user can't connect with IG.

I tried with the httpClient call but got a CORS error.

Is there any other way to validate IG User without connection?

Comment: You cannot do that without any authentication method. You should use [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) for that.

Comment: can we do like open extra window and call-back function?